# Rails - couldn't find file 'jquery_ujs' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been working on integrating a wrap bootstrap template onto an app and had the index page working without bootstrap glyphicons and then changed something and I have reversed previous changes but no longer have jquery_ujs working without this error.

Here is my gemfile thus far:

```css
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jrails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

#view database in console
gem 'hirb'

# mysql database 
# gem 'mysql', '~> 2.9', '>= 2.9.1'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Here is my application.js:

```css
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

Here is my application.scss:

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.



 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree 
 *= require_self
*/
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile.

Comment: I replaced the items and did what you said and that fixed my problem. Thanks mate!

Comment: Out of curiousity, is there any reason that I would actually need jquery_ujs? I have removed it and things seem to be working just fine.

Comment: jquery-ujs is the unobtrusive implementation to allow you to use jQuery in a Rails app. You can read about it in detail at https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs

Comment: Thanks! Just found out that if it's not including scaffolding will have some glitches when trying to delete entries but you have to also include  "//= require jquery_ujs" in your application.js Appreciate all of your help!